# Incompatible type: String cannot be converted to File

Tags: java, android

```
   GridView gv;
   ArrayList<File> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_yearbook);

    list = imageReader (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Mypath");

    gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.ImageGV);
    gv.setAdapter(new GridAdapter());
}


ArrayList<File> imageReader(File root) {

    ArrayList<File> a = new ArrayList<>();

    File[] files = root.listFiles();
    for (int i =0; i< files.length; i++) {
        if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
            a.addAll(imageReader(files[i]));
        }
        else {
            if ( files[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")) {
                a.add(files[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return a;
}
```

So i was trying to make my `imageReader` read a certain directory in my `sdcard` to show a array of images in my program. However i encountered an error on the line `list = imageReader (Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirecctory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Mypath");`, it says that  `java.io.file` cannot be converted to `java.io.string`. How do i fix this, i googled for hours and i cant really find a solution to it

Comment: you are passing a `String` instead`of `File` to the function.

Answer (score 2):

Use the File's constructor that takes two parameters. The first is the directory the second the name of the file or of the destination directory

```
list = imageReader(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Mypath"))
```

this way the system takes care of the separator too. Be also aware that

`listFiles()` can return null. So you should check against null values before starting looping

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
list = imageReader(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Mypath"));
```

Comment: That was a quick reply Thanks! it solved my problem, I was confused for literally hours

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this ( you need to handle the exception too):

```
try{

list = imageReader(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Mypath"));

}catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
  //ex handler code
}
```